# Unicode error using to_csv DESPITE specifying encoding = 'utf-8'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write a dataframe to a csv file like this:

`df.to_csv(path, index = True, header = True)`

But I keep getting this error:

**SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape**

I checked the forums here and saw that people were recommending adding an encoding parameter in the to_csv method. So I tried this

```
df.to_csv(path, index = True, header = True, encoding = 'utf-8')
```

But I keep getting the same error! Could someone please explain how to fix this?

**Note**: The source files I used to create this dataframe were a mix of csv, xls, and txt files. I tried specifying encoding = 'utf-8' on each of the read_csv and read_excel methods I used as well, but I still get the same error while using to_csv.

Here are my read methods:

```
iap = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\revenue.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')

installs = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\installs.xlsx', encoding = 'utf-8')

ecpm = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\eCPM org.txt', encoding = 'utf-8')

ads = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\total_ads_watched.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Comment: Just use forward slash "/" and see

Comment: `xls` is a binary format, not text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should try with absolute path.

`df.to_csv("/home/anand/file.csv", index = True, header = True, encoding = 'utf-8')`

However worth to look at the [String literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

> String literals can be enclosed within single quotes (i.e. '...') or
>   double quotes (i.e. "..."). They can also be enclosed in matching
>   groups of three single or double quotes (these are generally referred
>   to as triple-quoted strings).
>
> The backslash character (i.e. ) is used to escape characters which
>   otherwise will have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash
>   itself, or the quote character. String literals may optionally be
>   prefixed with a letter r or R. Such strings are called raw strings and
>   use different rules for backslash escape sequences.
>
> In triple-quoted strings, unescaped newlines and quotes are allowed,
>   except that the three unescaped quotes in a row terminate the string.
>
> Unless an r or R prefix is present, escape sequences in strings are
>   interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard C.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. But could you explain why this problem exists? For instance, what's the difference between using a `/' and a '\' (Like I was using before)? Also when I specify 'C:' at the start of my path I get a permission denied error, but when I remove it, it works fine. Why is this?

Comment: You can use \\ instead  into your path instead of \ as the syntax \uXXXX defines a unicode escape code whereas \\ escapes the escape code and lets you use it just fine,  also `'c:\\'` does not autocomplete, `r'c:\'` does not autocomplete, `'c:/'` autocompletes correctly.